# Adobe Illustrator - Hiding masked portions from selection? Cutting or masking a muti-layer and already masked section?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

It's difficult for me to explain what I'm trying to achieve, hopefully this image helps illustrate what I want to do.

[image]

This is the final product I'm trying to achieve (done in photoshop).

[image]

When I try to mask the square area it screws with the other masking layers I have going on. Not sure if this complexity of masking can be done in illustrator? Or, I'm doing it completely wrong..

Comment: Why not remove the square from the circle section, before you then use that circle to mask the stuff beneath it?  That way, the mask you are applying already has the desired cut outs missing

Answer (score 1):

Draw a circle the same size and thickness as the blue circle. Cut out the square from the new circle in the same place as above. Do this by selecting square and circle and hitting pathfinder/divide, ungroup and delete square. Your new circle is now a C shape. Place it exactly over the blue C, select both, right click and select Make clipping mask. You should now have your blue C with no dangley bits. Should reproduce fine in PS.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure all the elements of the circle logo are grouped, so you can
   easily select it.
2. Draw a circle, then a square, then position them over your logo.
3. Select both the circle and the square, and hit the `Minus Front`
   button in the Path Finder to make a circle shape with the square cut
   out of it.
4. Use that shape as your clipping mask, and apply it to the circle
   logo, by selecting both the logo group and the mask, then click
   `Object` > `Clipping Mask` > `Make`.

See the example showing the clipping mask in red, and applied to the logo.

[image: example of clipping mask]